# Scraping Table with mulitple pages but from single url

Tags: python, selenium, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from website KKP. The tables exist some pages but all of the pages use the same url. I am very new to web scraping data. I am currently using selenium to scraping table but that only contains the one first page, but I want scraping all the pages. Some of days of i always try to searching via google and seeing tutuorial in youtube but I still stuck. Link and my current code are below. I have no problem if you using BeautifulSoup to scraping data. I hope someone can help me. Thank you

website : http://www.ppk-kp3k.kkp.go.id/direktori-pulau/index.php/public_c/propinsi/11

```
from selenium import webdriver

from kora.selenium import wd
wd.get("http://www.ppk-kp3k.kkp.go.id/direktori-pulau/index.php/public_c/propinsi/11")

wd.maximize_window()

with open('pulau_scrapping_aceh_lengkap4.csv','w') as file:
  file.write('Pulau; Provinsi; Kabupaten \n')

pulau = wd.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]')
provinsi = wd.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]/tbody/tr/td[2]')
kabupaten = wd.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]/tbody/tr/td[3]')

row_data = []

for k in range(6):
  with open('pulau_scrapping_aceh_lengkap4.csv','a') as file:
    for i in range(len(pulau)):
      file.write(pulau[i].text + ';' + provinsi[i].text + ';' + kabupaten[i].text + '\n')
    
    next = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0_last"]')
    next.click()
  file.close()
wd.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire table is in the `HTML` source, so you can grab it with this (and there's no need for `selenium`):

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

link = 'http://www.ppk-kp3k.kkp.go.id/direktori-pulau/index.php/public_c/propinsi/11'
pd = pd.read_html(requests.get(link).text, flavor="bs4")[-1]
print(pd)
```

Output:

```
                  Pulau Propinsi             Kabupaten  Kecamatan Kependudukan
0          SIMEULUE CUT     ACEH    KABUPATEN SIMEULUE        NaN    Tidak Ada
1          SALAUT BESAR     ACEH    KABUPATEN SIMEULUE        NaN    Tidak Ada
2                  RAYA     ACEH   KABUPATEN ACEH JAYA        NaN    Tidak Ada
3                  RUSA     ACEH  KABUPATEN ACEH BESAR        NaN    Tidak Ada
4              BENGGALA     ACEH           KOTA SABANG        NaN    Tidak Ada
..                  ...      ...                   ...        ...          ...
256  Kualakepeng Mbelen     ACEH     KOTA SUBULUSSALAM        NaN    Tidak Ada
257         Tanahtumbuh     ACEH     KOTA SUBULUSSALAM        NaN    Tidak Ada
258       Tualang Kedep     ACEH     KOTA SUBULUSSALAM        NaN    Tidak Ada
259      Tualang Mbelen     ACEH     KOTA SUBULUSSALAM        NaN    Tidak Ada
260                 NaN      NaN                   NaN        NaN          NaN

[261 rows x 5 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

For scraping all the pages, using selenium you need to switch to those pages(Pagination), extract and store the table data in a file/list.
Below code will switch to all the pages of the given URL.

```
    pagenumber = 2
    driver.get("http://www.ppk-kp3k.kkp.go.id/direktoripulau/index.php/public_c/propinsi/11")
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,500)")
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(pagenumber)).click()
            time.sleep(5)
            #Code to retrieve the data from tables.
            pagenumber+=1

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
```